# Returning errno from main

Tags: c, errno

I have a code that is structured in such way:

```
main(){
 if(...){
  perror(... < 0);
  res = -1;
  goto cleanup;
 }
 ...
 if(... < 0){
  perror(...);
  res = -2;
  goto cleanup;
 }
 ...
cleanup:
 close(fd);
 return res;
}
```

I thought that I would return some meaningful errors from main. But went too lazy. Now I want to shrink my code a bit. I want to structure my code in a following way:

```
...
if(... < 0){
 perror(...);
 goto cleanup;
}
...
if(... < 0){
 perror(...);
 goto cleanup;
}
cleanup:
 close(fd);
 return errno; // return from main
```

Is it a good practice to do it in such way?

Comment: Not a good close reason, because the answers would definitely better not *primarily* be based on a option, but on facts (see [this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51004322/694576)).

Comment: Can't see any opinion based answers at this point in time. The answers had supplied me with some valuable information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

errno variable can be modified by [perror](https://linux.die.net/man/3/perror) and [close](https://linux.die.net/man/2/close). If you want to return errno, you need to save it first, so if a perror call fails it doesn't modify your errno value:

```
int main() {
    int errnosav = 0;
    ...
    errno = 0;
    if (some_function_that_modifies_errno() < 0) {
     errnosav = errno;
     perror(...);
     goto cleanup;
    }
    ...
    if (some_other_function_that_modifies_errno() < 0) {
     errnosav = errno;
     perror(...);
     goto cleanup;
    }
    cleanup:
     close(fd);
     return errnosav; // return from main
}
```

And that is just the same as the first version, but you have no control over the returned value.

> I thought that I would return some meaningful errors from main.

With the first version you return meaningful errors from main. If your program returns -1, you know that the first `if` failed. If you program returns -2 you know that your second `if` failed. From the perror message, you know what value the errno has. If you know what function failed and what the errno value is, you can check the function manual for the explanation of the errno value. If your program returns errno, you don't know which call failed. And without knowing which call failed, you don't know how to interpret the errno value.

Comment: Sigh. I guess I should stick to the first(more tedious) way of doing things.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it that way, (given you correct the problems brought forward by @Kamil Cuk) but you should know that many (most?) shells only read 8 bits of the exit code from programs. This means that if errno values ever exceed 255 and your program returns one of those errors, the shell would incorrectly report your error code. It can be seen at http://www.ioplex.com/~miallen/errcmp.html that errno codes have reached at least the value 252, ("Function not implemented" for HP-UX 11.22) so this is not an unreasonable scenario.

To be pedantic, shells also present to the user exit codes of 128+N where N is the signal number that terminated a process, so N>127 could also be a concern, but considering that the number of signals is hardly growing at all, I think this is less of a concern.

Comment: "*You could do it that way*", better not, because, no this would not necessarily work. As `errno` might very well be modify be any function called on the program's way out. (`close()` in the OPs 2nd snippet).

Comment: @user109923 Your point taken.

Comment: @alk Yes, I was assuming the case where it was implemented correctly. I have edited my answer to clarify that point.